# Node.js. Working with the real path of local files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, file, input

I'm new in Node.js and I'm doing a local App with Node.js+HTML5+Javascript with which I would like to move files from one local folder to another local folder. The main functionality of this app is to get a local file "A", read its content, copy this content encrypted in another file "B", and then store "B" in other location and finally delete file "A" in the local system. The problem that I've found is on getting the real path of the first file, and I know that it is difficult to get it (as I've seen in several discussions) for security reasons, but I really need it in order to delete file "A". I realised that with my current code I only can get this real path in IE explorer. The main part of the code involved is the following, in which I'm only able to get the file name in both Firefox and Chrome:

**index.ejs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="../scripts/get_file.js"></script>
      <title><%= title %></title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    </head>
 <body>
   <form method='get' action='/moveFile'>
     <div id="page-wrapper">
       <h1>File Browser</h1>
       <div>
         Select a file: 
         <input type="file" name="fileInput" id="fileInput">
         <input type="submit" value="Upload File"/>
       </div>
     </div>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**get_file.js:**

```
window.onload = function() {
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
        fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
        });
}
```

**fs_controller.js:**

```
exports.moveFile = function(req,res) {
    console.log(req.query.fileInput);
};
```

I've tried with the following options:

- I've seen that bodyparser is only used for express 3.0, and I have
  express 4.13.1.
- I've tried with Busboy, without results.
- I've tried with [filepath utility](https://www.npmjs.com/package/filepath), but it returns the path
  where is the main script of the application, so it's not useful for
  this case.
- Formidable only returns a tmp path.
- I've tried with multiparty, and it also returns a tmp path.
- The only solution that may be could work is to modify some properties
  in Firefox, like
  netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
  and in Chrome, with --allow-file-access-from-files. However, I think
  that it's not a clean solution.

I dont know if there are better solutions with Node.js to make this type of app. The main features that I actually need is to work with local files and folders (all types of basic operations with them), and to have a little database for storing the users of the app, and I would like to implement it with a MVC design pattern.

Thanks for your effort!

Comment: If it's a local app why are you even using express? If you want full access to the local file system in a JS+HTML5 app then use [Electron](https://github.com/atom/electron) or [NW.js](http://nwjs.io/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @VadimMacagon ! I will follow your advice, because I would like to make a local application. Which of the two options would you recommend to me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say Electron, but my answer is biased because I'm currently using Electron and have never used NW.js. The way I see it Electron aims to be lean and mean, they don't like adding features that aren't provided by the [Chromium Content module](https://www.chromium.org/developers/content-module) and prefer that developers use Node modules to fill in any gaps left by the missing Chrome APIs. In contrast NW.js aims to provide access to many Chrome APIs, to the point of being able to run actual Chrome Apps. It's easier for the Electron team to keep up with new Chromium & Node releases.

Comment: Okeey thanks for your advice!:)